# How to remove wasp nest and let them leave

Tags: pest-control, pest

I find that there are some wasps flying around my house, and even built their honeycomb near the roof or soffit vent.  Are there any methods to remove them or let these wasps leave? Thanks.

Comment: The question is how to convince them to leave (gently), not how to exterminate them.

Comment: We like bees, not wasps.  Don't let them leave when you have a chance to kill those pesky buggers!

Answer (score 2):

As Ed B. commented,  by knocking down the nest, you'll convince the wasps to leave and build a new nest elsewhere.  It's not necessary to spray -- at least from the point of view of getting them to leave! -- as they'll abandon a fallen nest.  The difficulty comes in whacking the nest without getting a swarm attacking you.  If you're fast :-) you can wait for a very cool night, hit the nest with a long pole, and run inside.

Otherwise, some spray to at least kill the exterior wasps and dissuade insiders from coming out a poisoned entrance should precede the knocking-down step.

Comment: The paperwasps I've dealt with in PA frequently have rebuilt in the same location if I just used a high pressure garden hose to knock down/destroy their nest without poisoning it and killing all the inhabitants first.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this multiple times, all successfully: At night, when they're calm, take a plastic jar or cup (see-through is important) with a mouth as wide as the nest. Put a crumpled paper towel in the bottom. This will absorb shock so the nest remains intact.  Bring some thin cardboard that can cover the jar opening.

With one hand, place the jar over the nest with the rim against the surface the nest is attached to.  Scrape the nest off the surface by sliding the jar sideways, keeping the lid against the surface. Once the nest is detached. Bring in the cardboard in and slip it between the jar and the surface.

Now take the jar and cardboard as one and place them on the ground somewhere away from normal activity with the cardboard on the top. At this point I usually take a long broom handle or spray water to knock off the cardboard and then run inside.

Answer (score 0):

Wasps can be dangerous especially if you are allergic so I would suggest hiring a professional exterminator because they have the right tools and safety gear to do the job properly. Wasps are very territorial and can sense danger so they will attack and sting. If the nest is near your home, just call a professional to do it for you. They will treat the area and also remove the nest for you to avoid secondary infestation.

Answer (score 0):

If the wasps can be tolerated until winter, it's much safer to knock down the nest when it's below freezing. I take a 5 gallon bucket and jab at the nest with a broom handle until it's all in the bucket. Never had one fly out while I was doing it. Then I spray the soffits with a natural repellent - usually a peppermint oil spray, such as EcoSmart Wasp & Hornet Killer. Safe around people and pets. I never use poisons. If you spray the soffits every few months with peppermint oil, you're less likely to get paper wasps. They hate the stuff. Helps keep some spiders away as well.